# How to iterate over a map in a const method

Tags: c++

Currently i have something like this

```
int Myclass::MyMethod(const std::string &name) const
{
   for (std::map<std::string,int>::iterator it=mIndex.begin(); it!=mIndex.end(); ++it)<--Error
   {
   }

}
```

Now I get the error

```
`Error  1   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from`'std::_Tree<_Traits>::const_iterator' to 'std::_Tree<_Traits>::iterator'`
```

Any suggestions on how i can iterate over the map in a constant method ?

Comment: What about using `const_iterator`?

Comment: The compiler message is telling you what type to use.  Are you asking *why*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a `const_iterator`:

```
for (std::map<std::string,int>::const_iterator it=mIndex.begin(); it!=mIndex.end(); ++it)
```

which can be achieved with less typing by letting `auto` deduce the type:

```
for (auto it = mIndex.begin(); it!=mIndex.end(); ++it) { ...
```

Or use a range based for loop instead:

```
for (const auto& p : mIndex) { .... }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int Myclass::MyMethod(const std::string &name) const
{
   for (std::map<std::string,int>::const_iterator it=mIndex.begin(); it!=mIndex.end(); ++it)
   {
   }

}
```

or

```
int Myclass::MyMethod(const std::string &name) const
{
   for (auto it=mIndex.cbegin(); it!=mIndex.cend(); ++it)
   {
   }

}
```

or

```
int Myclass::MyMethod(const std::string &name) const
{
   for (auto& elem :mIndex.)
   {
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems the iterator needs to be `const`, you must use `const_iterator` instead of `iterator`. Another way after C++11 is to use `auto` keyword.

```
for (auto it=mIndex.begin(); it!=mIndex.end(); ++it)
```